# How to wait till the response comes from the $resource request, in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, resources

I am going to tell you a bit about what I am doing so you may help me. I am reading some records from a .txt and for **each** record I need to make some verifications, in order to do this, I make a $resource call to my backend service to get the **regex** which will be use to verified **each record.**

**I need to wait for the response of the service**. I have this (I use $recourse for the get with .factory) :

```
function findRegex() {
        var data;
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        data = findRegexCountry.get({ number: $scope.number }).$promise.then(function(data) {
            deferred.resolve(data.body);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

and I do can, successfully, use it in the function I need like this:

```
//validar tipo 2
        var bool = false;
        if (tipo == 2) {
            if (numbers.test(split[0]) && numbers.test(split[1])) {
                $scope.number = '58';

                findRegex().then(function(data) {
                    bool = true;
                    // console.log('data', data);
                    $scope.regexResponse = data;
                    regex_all = data.regex_all;
                    regex_length = data.regex_length;
                    regex_justCountry = data.regex_justCountry;
                    regex_justCarriers = data.regex_justCarriers;

                    console.log('1. regex_justCarriers ', regex_justCarriers);
                    console.log('1. regex_length ', regex_length);
                });

                //nothing here :( SOS
                console.log('2. regex_justCarriers ', regex_justCarriers);
```

This works, but I **NEED** to wait for the response in order to continue with my code, let me tell you why (maybe you can give me a better idea).

I can't make all the logic inside **findRegex()**, first of all because I don't want to make this call *everytime* I read a record from the .txt. I want to get the regex from the service one time and if this first record I am checking is a valid record for me, the other ones will be using the variables I already got with the first call to the service, there are other reasons, but mainly this, I can't make all the code I need to inside this.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `findRegex` is returning a promise object, not the processed data. `findRegex().then(...)` also returns immediately with an another promise. You can continue doing the things needed inside the first then, or you can extend the promise chain with another .then(). And at last but not least, you need to take care the possibility of errors with a catch like this:

```
        findRegex().then(function(data) {
            bool = true;
            // console.log('data', data);
            $scope.regexResponse = data;
            regex_all = data.regex_all;
            regex_length = data.regex_length;
            regex_justCountry = data.regex_justCountry;
            regex_justCarriers = data.regex_justCarriers;

            console.log('1. regex_justCarriers ', regex_justCarriers);
            console.log('1. regex_length ', regex_length);
            return data // just in case, if you need it later
        }).then(function(data) {
            console.log('2. regex_justCarriers ', regex_justCarriers);
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log('something went wrong', error);
        })
```

Comment: Thank you!! I will add the catch immediately!! 

Is there another way to return the processed data? If I added this lines, it does work, but still the same issue. Thank you very much in advance for helping me :)!!!

Comment: You can use async await, but i suggest first of all, try to understand more deep what promises are.
Start [here](https://eu.udacity.com/course/javascript-promises--ud898)